# Overflow and scrolling

Tags: html, css

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sruHf/1/

I want the images to be next to each other, and to scroll the horizontally only.
 Currently, the images are next to each other...but it wraps down to another line...instead of continuing to stay next to each other.

Any idea how I can do that?
I tried with `overflow-x : auto` and `overflow-y : hidden`, but it does not seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the CSS.

Comment: Ah! I knew it was something with white-space...Thanks a lot for your time!